# Public Website in Salesforce

Tags: site.com, community-builder

What are the options to create public websites in Salesforce.

As per my knowledge, we can do the same using Force.com Sites & Site.com. However, I think my knowledge is a bit old now. I am not seeing Site.com option now & in some documentation it is mentioned that Site.com is superseded by Community Builder.

As far as i know, Community builder is used to create authenticated user(Customer/Partner Community) and not public websites.

Can anyone shed some light here? Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Raj

Comment: you can also create public website in community builder and it also you to provide users authentication. You should go with community

Answer (score 0):

I just double checked in a pretty fresh DE Org. From Setup -> Develop -> Sites. Looks like all that is still there.

Here's the documentation for [Force.com Sites Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_overview.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=204.13).

There's also some information on the Communities angle for public wesites [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=communities_sites_which.htm&type=0&language=en_US).

So it looks like you can use both Sites and Communities to build public websites on Force.com

Answer (score 0):

Communities indeed supersede sites on the SF platform. You can enable public access to a community as well as create a public knowledge base for distribution of your public FAQ's etc.

Relevant documentation can be found here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/networks_public_access.htm

Once you've got people visiting your community, consider funnelling them through a registration process (setup again in community builder) in order to increase engagement.